# Measure - exercise 22 from Folland

Tags: measure-theory

I'm doing some exercises from Folland's real analysis book. Exercise 18 is done and should help to do exercise 22, but I'm stuck.

[image: first]

The definition of completion is given below.

[image: second]

This is not homework, I'm doing this by myself to learn. If possible, I would appreciate a complete answer. Thank you!

PS: my idea was to try to show that $\mathcal{M}^\ast = \overline{\mathcal{M}}$, then the uniqueness would follow from theorem 1.9 and Carathéodory's theorem (which guarantees that $\mu^\ast$ is complete). I don't see how I can do that and don't know if this is the right idea. That's why I'm asking for help here.

Comment: you made the question 23?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M}$. Have $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\mu$, $\mathscr{M}^*$ the $\mu^*$-measurable sets and $\overline{\mu}$ the measure $\mu^*$ restricted to $\mathscr{M}^*$. We want to prove $\overline{\mu}$ on $\mathscr{M}^*$ is the completion of the measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathscr{M}$. We first prove a lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $(X,\mathscr{F},\nu)$ be a measure space, and let $\overline{\mathscr{F}}$ be the completion of $\mathscr{F}$ according to the definition$$\overline{\mathscr{F}} := \{E \cup F\text{ }|\text{ }E \in \mathscr{F},\,F \subset N \text{ for some }N \in \mathscr{F} \text{ such that }\nu(N) = 0\}.$$Then,$$\overline{\mathscr{F}} := \{G - D\text{ }|\text{ }G \in \mathscr{F},\text{ }D \subset N \text{ for some }N \in \mathscr{F}\text{ such that }\nu(N) = 0\}.$$

*Proof.* Take $E \cup F \in \overline{\mathscr{F}}$, where $E \in \mathscr{F}$ and $F \subset N$ for some $N \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $\nu(N) = 0$. Then $$E \cup F = E \cup N - (N - (F \cup E)).$$ Note that $E \cup N \in \mathscr{F}$ and $N - (F \cup E) \subset N$.

Conversely, consider $G - D$, where $G - D$, where $G \in \mathscr{F}$ and there is $N \in \mathscr{F}$ with $\nu(N) = 0$ such that $D \subset N$. Then $$G - D = (G - N) \cup [(N \cap G) - D],$$ and $G - N \in \mathscr{F}$ and $(N \cap G) - D \subset N$. So we are done. $\square$

Remember that $$\overline{M} := \{G \cup F\text{ }|\text{ }B \in \mathscr{M},\,F \subset N\text{ for some }N \in \mathscr{M}\text{ such that }\mu(N) = 0\}$$and for such a set $G \cup F$ as in this definition, $\overline{\mu}(G \cup F) := \mu(G)$.

We want to prove that $\mathscr{M}^* = \overline{\mathscr{M}}$ and $\mu^*(E) = \overline{\mu}(E)$ for $E \in \mathscr{M}^*$. We know from Exercise 18 that if $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, there exists $B$ in $\mathscr{M}_{\sigma \delta}$ such that $E \subset B$ and $\mu^*(B - E) = 0$. However, because $\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathscr{M}_{\sigma\delta} = \mathscr{M}$ and $B \in \mathscr{M}$. By similar reasoning, since $B - E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, there exists $C \in \mathscr{M}$ such that $B - E \subset C$ and $\mu^*(C) = \mu(C) = 0$. Because $E = B - (B - E)$, where $B \in \mathscr{M}$, our lemma tells us that $E \in \overline{\mathscr{M}}$. This estalblishes that $\mathscr{M}^* \subset \overline{\mathscr{M}}$.

The converse, $\overline{\mathscr{M}} \subset \mathscr{M}^*$, is true since any set of outer measure $0$ is in $\mathscr{M}^*$. So if $G \in \mathscr{M} \subset \mathscr{M}^*$ and $F \subset N$, where $N \in \mathscr{M}$ and $\mu(N) = 0$, $F \in \mathscr{M}^*$ as well, and thus $G \cup F \in \mathscr{M}^*$.

Finally, if $G \in \mathscr{M}$ and $F \subset N$, where $N \in \mathscr{M}$ and $\mu(N) = 0$, then we have that $$\mu(G)  = \mu^*(G) \le \mu^*(G \cup F) \le \mu^*(G) + \mu^*(F)  = \mu^*(G) = \mu(G).$$ Thus $$\mu^*(G \cup F) = \mu(G) = \overline{\mu}(G).$$

Answer (score 6):

I will show that $\mathscr M^*=\overline{\mathscr M}$. From Theorem 1.9 and Carathéodory's theorem it follows, indeed, that $\mu^*|\mathscr M^*$ is *the* completion of $\mu$, since $\mu^*|\mathscr M^*$ is a complete measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr M^*=\overline{\mathscr M}$ and it extends $\mu$ by Proposition 1.13.

Consider a measure space $(X,\mathscr M,\mu)$ as in Exercise 22 and suppose that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. In the language of Exercise 18, $\mathscr M=\mathscr M_{\sigma}=\mathscr M_{\sigma\delta}$, because $\mathscr M$ is not only an algebra but also a $\sigma$-algebra. Then, by Exercise 18(b) and (c), $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable (that is, $E\in\mathscr M^*$) if and only if

$$\text{$\exists B\in\mathscr M$ such that $E\subseteq B$ and $\mu^*(B\setminus E)=0$.}\tag{1}$$

Now, $(1)$ is equivalent to the following (note that $B\setminus E=E^c\setminus B^c$):
$$\text{$\exists B\in\mathscr M$ such that $B^c\subseteq E^c$ and $\mu^*(E^c\setminus B^c)=0$.}\tag{2}$$

Next, $\mu^*(E^c\setminus B^c)=0$ is equivalent to requiring that $E^c\setminus B^c$ be a subset of a $\mu$-null set (using the definition of $\mu^*$ and its completeness—see below for details). Therefore, $(2)$ is, in turn, equivalent to:
$$\text{$\exists B\in\mathscr M$ such that $B^c\subseteq E^c$ and $E^c\setminus B^c\subseteq N$ for some $N\in\mathscr N$,}\tag{3}$$
where $\mathscr N$ is as defined in Theorem 1.9. In other words, $(3)$ requires that $E^c$ be able to be expressed as the union of a $\mathscr M$-set $B^c$ and a subset $E^c\setminus B^c$ of a $\mu$-null set $N$. That is, $(3)$ is equivalent to $E^c\in\overline {\mathscr M}$ in the language of Theorem 1.9, or, since $\overline{\mathscr M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $E\in\overline {\mathscr M}$.

**Conclusion:** $E\in\mathscr M^*$ iff $(1)$ iff $(2)$ iff $(3)$ iff $E^c\in\overline{\mathscr M}$ iff $E\in\overline{\mathscr M}$. Therefore, $\mathscr M^*=\overline{\mathscr M}$.

---

In what follows, let me prove that if $B\subseteq X$, then $\mu^*(B)=0$ if and only if $B\subseteq N$ for some $N\in\mathscr M$ such that $\mu(N)=0$. Necessity follows from Carathéodory's theorem: since $\mu^*|\mathscr M^*$ is complete and $\mu^*|\mathscr M=\mu$ (see Proposition 1.13), it follows that if $B\subseteq N$ for some $N\in\mathscr M(\subseteq\mathscr M^*)$ and $\mu(N)=0$, then $B\in\mathscr M^*$ and $\mu^*(B)=0$ given that $\mu^*(N)=\mu(N)=0$.

As for sufficiency, suppose that $\mu^*(B)=0$. Then, using the infimum definition of $\mu^*$, for any $n\in\mathbb N$, there exist sets $\{A_{nk}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathscr M$ such that
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{nk}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{nk})<\frac{1}{n}$$
and $B\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{nk}$. Now, let $N\equiv\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{nk}\in\mathscr M$. Clearly, $B\subseteq N$ and $\mu(N)=0$ since $\mu(N)<1/n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$.